# upgrading the version of eclipselink being used in payara server

Tags: java, glassfish, payara

I have an application falling foul of the following known issue:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/pull/117

It's a bug affecting some versions of eclipselink, notably the version of eclipselink bundled with `payara 5.182` which is the latest.

```
[2018-08-14T15:34:25.323+0200] [Payara 5.182] [INFO] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/C:/Projects/mcp/mcp/war/target/mcp/WEB-INF/lib/integration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar_tlmon] [tid: _ThreadID=53 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1534253665323] [levelValue: 800] [[  EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1.qualifier]]   
EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1.qualifier]]
```

I have changed my **`POM.XML`** file to use a later version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This doesn't seem to impact the version used by payara.
How do I force payara to use the fixed version of eclipse link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download the latest version of eclipselink:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Replace the files in glassfish\modules with the ones above.

Comment: Looks like it should be upgraded from the next release: https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/3045